# Wifi Internet access problem

Tags: wifi

I installed elementary os loki recently. There was a problem that the wifi kept asking for password again and again. I run a terminal command to disable 802.11n. The command solved that problem but later the wifi kept losing the internet connection if i did not use it for just 10 sec. If I download something then it is working perfectly but while browsing if I pause on a page, it loses internet connection and then I have to restart the wifi. The main problem is that I reinstalled elementary but that too did not solve this problem. Thanks in advance.
My wifi adaptor is BCM43142.

iwconfig

`wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"TP-LINK_806A"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: EC:08:6B:F6:80:6A
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
lo        no wireless extensions.
enp2s0    no wireless extensions.`

Comment: Please edit the question to include results for `iwconfig`

Comment: Do the results change when you get disconnected?

Comment: No they are the same

Answer (score 1):

What it sounds like is that your router(not your adapter) has an idle timeout, with the time set to a very low number. Assuming you have access, you could either find out if it's set that way through the router's Web interface (preferred), or do a factory reset on your router.

If you do the latter, make sure you record all of your settings, and if it's a company router, get IT involved, because no changes since the router was NIB will be saved.